# How to remove the gap between tabs and fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

[image]

I'm currently working on a project but currently stuck on removing the gap between the tabs and the included fragments between the two tabs

Comment: please add your xml layout code

Comment: That is probably padding of the root element in your layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i actually found it just now it's the CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout
after removing this line ~ android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ~ it's fixed
thank you for replying